# Получить значения свойств анонимного объекта

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты

Данный вопрос возник на основе вопроса из тестов по JavaScript.

В первом случае мы можем получить как название свойств объекта используя `key`, так и их значения, используя `person[key]`.
В случае если мы используем "анонимный" объект, мы можем аналогично получить имена свойств, но как быть с их значениями? Возможно ли это?

Не будем вдаваться для чего это может понадобиться, просто пытливый ум ищет правды.

```js
var person = {
  name: 'John',
  age: 30
};

for (var key in person) {
  console.log(person[key]);
}

for (var key in {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30
  }) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

P.S. Вариант сделать что-то похожее естественно не подходит под условия "анонимности" )

```
for(var key in nextPerson = {name: 'John', age: 30}) {
 console.log(nextPerson[key]);
}
```

Comment: Никак вы не сможете получить эти значения.

Comment: Пришли с коллегой к этому выводу, но вдруг найдутся джедаи обладающие такой силой )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-for-in-and-for-of-statements-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation)

```
IterationStatement : for ( var ForBinding in Expression ) Statement

1. Let keyResult be ? ForIn/OfHeadEvaluation(« », Expression, enumerate).
2. Return ? ForIn/OfBodyEvaluation(ForBinding, Statement, keyResult, enumerate, varBinding, labelSet).
```

В само тело не передается вычисленное значение `Expression` (в данном случае значение литерала объекта), вместо этого передается итератор `keyResult` значения из которого и будут доступны в теле цикла.

Так как нет доступа к значению, то и обратиться к нему невозможно.

---

Без сохранения значения в переменную получить и значение и ключ можно заменив цикл [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) на [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Этот вид цикла позволяет использовать свои [итераторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), а значит возможен следующий вариант:

```js
for (var key of {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*() {
      for (var i in this) {
        yield [i, this[i]]
      }
    }
  }) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Либо можно использовать существующий метод [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
for (var key of Object.entries({
    name: 'John',
    age: 30
  })) {
  console.log(key);
}
```

Comment: там возможно знания ключа и не нужно, а просто значения свойства, так что `of`, возможно хватит и без итератора.

Comment: @teran, не хватит, потому что для `of` нужен итератор как раз, в объекте его нет :-) Возможно конечно хватит и `Object.values` который только значения итерирует, но тут все от задачи зависит.

Comment: и действительно.

Comment: второй вариант выглядит изящнее

Comment: @ТукмачевПавел, все зависит от того, что и как надо возвращать. В своем итераторе можно любые значения выдавать, в том числе и каким-либо образом преобразованные. В стандартных функциях, соответственно, реализованы конкретные итераторы.